# Calling an Oracle stored procedure that uses an output parameter from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am trying to execute a stored procedure on an Oracle 10g server, which returns its results in an output parameter, from a SQL Server 2008 query.

The Oracle stored procedure declaration looks like this:

```
 PROCEDURE MY_PROC(
     ID IN NUMBER,
     RESULT OUT CURSOR_TYPE);
```

How would I call this stored procedure from MS SQL Server 2008, using either OpenQuery or any method of querying Oracle, and be able to see the result set stored in 'RESULT'?

Comment: I'm thinking there may be a way to do this with [OPENROWSET](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2005/08/01/the-openrowset-trick-accessing-stored-procedure-output-in-a-select-statement.aspx) for SQL server, but I'm not sure about oracle.. There is this [blog post](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/blogs/matt/archive/2005/06/13/2221.aspx) which may provide direction for you.

Answer (score 0):

I did that from SQL SERVER to SQL SERVER and it's work well.
Maybe in Oracle you will need some chages.

here is my code in sql server

--drop proc proc_test_test
create proc proc_test_test
(

@a int,
@b int output

)
as
begin

set @b = @a*6+4

end

select *

from openrowset('type','server name';'user';'pass',

'declare @answer int  ;

exec db.dbo.proc_test_test @a = 1, @b = @answer output;

select @answer as a'
)